# document.getElementById('ID').style.cursor not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is the if statement not working here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>#myP{cursor:pointer;}</style>

<p id="myP">random text</p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">alert aaa</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    if(document.getElementById("myP").style.cursor=="pointer"){
        alert("aaa");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I want to know how to make the if statement work with a linked cursor like:

```
<style>#myP{cursor: url(../randomFolder/cursor.png) 5 8, auto;}</style>
```

Comment: The `.style` property of DOM element nodes only includes styles *directly* coded onto the element via a "style" attribute. It doesn't provide access to styles applied by CSS. You have to use something like `getComputedStyle()` to get that information.

Comment: Alright thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead :
`if (window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).cursor == 'pointer')`

Answer (score 1):

`.style` only works for inline CSS.  `window.getComputedStyle()` will let you retrieve styles set via non-inline CSS.

For your second question, matching the linked image cursor is a little trickier than just matching a simple string like "pointer", because you're including a path which will be canonicalized to the full URL, as you can see below ("https://stacksnippets.net" is included in the path even though it wasn't specified in the CSS.)  It's probably best to test for a substring of the full cursor value, so you don't run into problems where your code works on "yourdomain.com" but not on "www.yourdomain.com":

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var A = document.getElementById('a');
  var B = document.getElementById('b');

  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(A).cursor);
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(B).cursor);

  if (window.getComputedStyle(A).cursor == 'pointer') {
    console.log("A matched");
  }

  var bCursor = window.getComputedStyle(B).cursor;
  if (bCursor.indexOf('cursor.png') > -1) { // not hardcoding the full URL here
    console.log("B matched");
  }
}
```

```css
#a {
  cursor: pointer
}

#b {
  cursor: url(randomFolder/cursor.png) 5 8, auto;
}
```

```html
<p id="a">random text</p>
<p id="b">more random text</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">alert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery with css function and it will return you the kind of cursor which you need in a short code.

```
$('#myP').css('cursor')
```